# [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is my `app.js` file,

```
import "./bootstrap";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./routes";

import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

This is my `route.js` file,

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import App from "./views/Main.vue";
import Login from "./views/Login.vue";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            route: "/",
            name: "Home",
            component: App,
        },
        {
            route: "/login",
            name: "Login",
            component: Login,
        },
    ],
});

export default router;
```

This is my `App.vue` file,

```
<template>
    <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink to="/login">Login</RouterLink>
    <RouterView />
</template>

<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from "vue-router";
</script>
```

This is how my files are located,

[image]

I have defined the routes correctly I guess. But it throws me an error in the console saying,`[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/login"` . And the page doesn't load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have defined the routes correctly I guess.*

Almost there. But it's not `route`:

```js
{
  route: "/login",
  name: "Login",
  component: Login,
}
```

It's `path`:

```js
{
  path: "/login",
  name: "Login",
  component: Login,
}
```

See [Getting Started](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript).